# How to list all devices connected to your hotspot's WiFi network

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, wifi

I'm trying to get a list of IP addresses of all connected devices on my WiFi network created by my personal hotspot on iOS ,but can't seem to find any documentation on it.

I think that for Android I can use this two plugins:

- cordova-plugin-network-information
- cordova-plugin-networkinterface

On Ionic documentation I found this:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/hotspot/

Is there something similar that will work on iOS?

Comment: I am looking for same think and ready to use private libraries too. Do you know any private library doc that can be helpful?

Comment: I found this https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard but will keep looking

Comment: This seems promising https://github.com/jcesarmobile/my-phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/NetworkInterfacesPlugin

Comment: I suggest you take a look at it. https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan It pings all the possible IP addresses in the class and successful response means node is available. iOS 7 device hot spot gives an IP address in the 172.20.10.* range so you know what range to scan. Just try it bc my assumptions might turn out wrong too.